# struts2 contains test in iterator tag

Tags: java, struts2, iterator, contains

This is my code in jsp:

```
<s:iterator value="sources" status="sourceStatus">
  <s:property value="sourcesCheck"/>
  <s:property value="#sourceStatus.index"/>
  <s:if test="%{sourcesCheck.contains(#sourceStatus.index)}">
    true
  </s:if>
  <s:else>
    false
  </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

sourcesCheck is an array I pass from my action populated with values 0,1,2,3,4,5. The results on my jsp show 0,1,2,3,4,5 for sourcesCheck, however, the test is always false. Why? I have tried with both int and String values for sourcesCheck. How does contains work? If index is not a String or int, what is it?

Comment: The other option besides Ischin's answer would be to use something like Apache Commons' [ArrayUtils.contains](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) class, but IMO a real collection is a better idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code:

```
        <s:iterator value="sources" status="sourceStatus">
            <s:property value="sourcesCheck"/>
            <s:property value="#sourceStatus.index"/>
            <s:if test="%{#sourceStatus.index in sourcesCheck}">
                true
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                false
            </s:else>
        </s:iterator>
```

Comment: This also won't work; `sourcesCheck` is an array and will never equal an integer.

Comment: @DaveNewton And thanks for notifying. :) I misinterpreted sources as array and sourcesCheck as an integer property.

Comment: Thanks Dave and James, although I ended up using == and managed to get what I wanted with some manipulation, I tested this code and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Array doesn't have any methods to implement. Consider the [`java.util.List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

**For example** :

```
List<Integer> sourcesCheck = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Compare by [`java.util.List.contains(Integer)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
<s:if test="sourcesCheck.contains(#sourceStatus.index)">

</s:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be as follow

```
<s:if test="%{sourcesCheck.contains('#sourceStatus.index')}">
```

because you want to check a value not a variable.

Comment: How can the double quotes be used inside the expression?

Comment: @James Sometime the compiler can deal with it. A good example is JSTL. But in casse not use apostrophes.

Comment: In that case, the expression should be like test="%{sourcesCheck.contains('#sourceStatus.index')}"

Comment: Edited to reflect @JamesJithin's comment. Inside JSP tags no compiler will let you use the same quotes for both wrapping the attribute value and inside that value. It's different than when embedding a custom tag inside an HTML tag attribute.